# PHP need help in finding a certain index by direction,

Tags: php

So, I have a index. 0-etc. And I want to get a certain index number, through a direction.

What I have displayed on the frontend, is something like this:

```
0123
4567
89
```

If i'm on 0, and I want to go down. How will I know what index it is?

And I have no idea of how to do that.

EDIT:
I have an index list with 4 indexs, 0-3.
And I have an unlimited amount of columns (meaning, the number of columns change.)

Comment: Do you mean actually going to to the next row? Such as if you were to go down from 0, you get 4; and 1 > 5 > 9, etc.?

Comment: No. What I meant is I need to know if a direction has an index or not. And if it does, what that index is.

Comment: (number of elements in a row * current column number) eg. (4 * 1 = 4), step down again: (4 * 2 = 8). column count starts at zero. build a matrix and cater for your current position.

Comment: Please share your current attempt such that others can see what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your index into 2 dimensional array so each element is accessible via providing y (up/down) and x (left/right)

So this would be our matrix:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
}
```

So our '0' is $matrix[0][0], 1 is $matrix[0,1], 4 is $matrix[1, 0] etc.
Now we can access every element via $y and $x and get elements in desired direction by adding to $y (add 1 to go down, -1 to go up), or $x (add 1 to go right, -1 to go left).
If we go out of index bounds it means index doesnt exist (for example going left from 0).

```
<?php

$index = '0123456789';
$indexArray = str_split($index);
$matrix = array_chunk($indexArray, 4);

function move(array $matrix, string $current, string $direction) {
  foreach ($matrix as $y => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $x =>  $column) {
      if ($column === $current) {
        $position = [$y, $x];
      }
    }
  }

  if ($direction === 'up') {
    $vector = [-1,0];
  } elseif ($direction === 'down') {
    $vector = [1,0];
  } elseif ($direction === 'right') {
    $vector = [0,1];
  } elseif ($direction === 'left') {
    $vector = [0,-1];
  }

  return $matrix[$position[0] + $vector[0]][$position[1] + $vector[1]] ?? null;
}

var_dump(move($matrix, '0', 'down')); // 4
var_dump(move($matrix, '0', 'up')); // null
var_dump(move($matrix, '0', 'left')); // null
var_dump(move($matrix, '0', 'right')); // 1

var_dump(move($matrix, '6', 'down')); // null
var_dump(move($matrix, '6', 'up')); // 2
var_dump(move($matrix, '6', 'left')); // 5
var_dump(move($matrix, '6', 'right')); // 7
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! I ended up using something like what you did, except I used adding. I just since we were only using 1 move (up,left,down,right) once. I could just do 0+4=4, 1+4=5, etc. Still, very helpful though.